# Accuracy of a Set with a HashMap backing's contains() method?

Tags: java, hashmap, set, hashcode, hash-code-uniqueness

Hi I'm using a Set backed by a HashMap to keep track of what edges I have already traversed in a graph.
I was planning on keying the set by the result of adding the hashcodes of the data stored in each edge.

```
v.getData().hashCode() + wordV.getData().hashCode()
```

But how reliable is this when using contains to check to see if the edge is in the set? Couldn't I hypothetically get a false positive? Is there anyway to overcome this?

the exact statement that causes me concern is:

```
edgeSet.contains(v.getData().hashCode() + wordV.getData().hashCode())
```

thanks!

Oh by the way I'm using Java.

EDIT:

I should have made this clear in the question. In my graph there is no edge object, there are vertex objects which each hold a list of more vertex objects, which is the edge. So I guess the question that follows from that combined with your responses is:

Can I use a Set to store references to information as opposed to objects....?
i.e. can I store the result of adding the two hashcodes for the vertices' data objects?

EDIT2:

I am indeed using the Java library for my hashmap, I declare it as below:

```
Set<Integer> edgeSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Boolean>());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: from your question I couldn't tell whether you were using [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), or your own home rolled implementation. Be aware that Java's `HashSet` is simply a wrapper for a `HashMap` where the values are ignored. `HashSet.contains` simply calls `containsKey` on the inner map.

`HashMap.containsKey` uses the same lookup as `get`. That will compute the hash and use it to find the right bucket. From there it will walk the bucket and use `equals` until it finds the exact match. Assuming the element type implements both `hashCode` and `equals` correctly, there's no chance of getting a false positive using `containsKey` since `equals` is ultimately used to confirm.

The [relevant source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.getEntry%28java.lang.Object%29) is in the package-private method `getEntry`, which is used by both `containsKey` and `get`:

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash &&
            ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Can I use a Set to store references to information as opposed to
>   objects....? i.e. can I store the result of adding the two hashcodes
>   for the vertices' data objects?

No, you would need to implement a new class representing this information and store instances of it in the `Set`. This could be a simple POJO with a field for each piece of information, and with `hashCode` and `equals` overridden correctly.

Comment: Alright, gotcha. I guess I need to go make myself a wrapper class then....

Thanks!

Comment: @Ethan - Yep, exactly. One more note just in case: don't try to reuse these objects by changing them once they're instantiated. `HashMap` will not know to recompute the hashes. The best practice will be to make this new class [immutable](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29).

Answer (score 5):

Hash codes, by definition, will have collisions. Adding them together helps nothing.

You should make the edges of your graph support hashCode and equals, and simply put the edges in a hash set as you go.

```
class Edge { ... equals and hashCode ... }

HashSet<Edge> traversed = new HashSet<Edge>();
traversed.add(edge);
...
if(traversed.contains(edge)) ...
```

If you are numbering your edges instead, then Integer already has a good hash code and equals, so use it:

```
HashSet<Integer> traversed = new HashSet<Integer>();
if(traversed.contains(edgeNumber)) ...
traversed.add(3);
```

Comment: I don't actually have Edge objects, I have a list of vertices in each vertex

Comment: The answer still stands...you may choose to make an Edge class, or you can try to combine your vertices some other way...in general, shoot for clarity. If you're tight on space you could get into packing things into a long, but that would be a sin unless you'd actually tested how well it worked with a nice Edge abstraction...it is certainly easy to write.

Comment: BTW gnu.trove has some nice high performance collections if you end up wanting to store primitives.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you override both `hashCode()` and `equals()`, you'll be fine.  Hash codes are never guaranteed to be unique.  That said, you're kind of misusing the Set.  With storing classes with properly implemented `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods, methods such as `contains()`' will have perfect accuracy.  However, that's not how you're using it here.  As it sounds like you're almost building your own data structure / collection, you'll need to consider doing this the same way that the 'Hash' collections do - use a HashMap to store buckets of your hashes - the hash value as the key, and then a collection of whatever as the value to compare against.  This will allow you to quickly see if the parent map even has the hash you're looking for.  If not, you're done (false).  If it does, then you need to confirm that its "bucket" has the specific values you're looking for (true).